# Class 'View' incorrectly extends base class 'Backbone.View'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript

This error/warning appears in every file I try to extend from `Backbone.View`. The compiler still runs and the JavaScript works as expected. Even with an empty class it throws the same error:

```
/// <reference path="references/backbone.d.ts" />

module Test {
  export class View extends Backbone.View<Model> {

  }
}
```

The reference file I'm using is the latest from Boris Yankov's [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) library. The View class is defined as:

```
class View <TModel extends Model> extends Events {

  /**
   * Do not use, prefer TypeScript's extend functionality.
   **/
  private static extend(properties: any, classProperties?: any): any;

  constructor(options?: ViewOptions<TModel>);
  initialize(options?: ViewOptions<TModel>): void;

  /**
   * Events hash or a method returning the events hash that maps events/selectors to methods on your View.
   * For assigning events as object hash, do it like this: this.events = <any>{ "event:selector": callback, ... };
   * That works only if you set it in the constructor or the initialize method.
   **/
  events(): any;

  $(selector: string): JQuery;
  model: TModel;
  collection: Collection<TModel>;
  //template: (json, options?) => string;
  setElement(element: HTMLElement, delegate?: boolean): View<TModel>;
  setElement(element: JQuery, delegate?: boolean): View<TModel>;
  id: string;
  cid: string;
  className: string;
  tagName: string;

  el: any;
  $el: JQuery;
  setElement(element: any): View<TModel>;
  attributes: any;
  $(selector: any): JQuery;
  render(): View<TModel>;
  remove(): View<TModel>;
  make(tagName: any, attributes?: any, content?: any): any;
  delegateEvents(events?: any): any;
  undelegateEvents(): any;

  _ensureElement(): void;
}
```

It would help if the compiler was a little more verbose and told me *how* I'm extending the class incorrectly. Is there anything that's mandatory to extend the `Backbone.View` class and prevent this cryptic warning appearing on every view I have?

Or, can I at least suppress the warning? If I have this `View` class extended many times, it's going to get very difficult to find real errors at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new typescript project with VS2015 and added your code above. I don't get the error/warning so I guess it is based on something else in your environment/toolset.

Comment: Hmm I am using WebStorm so it could be. Though the definitions and compiler are from Microsoft's TypeScript library. WebStorm simply integrates them into its environment. What version of compiler are you using? I'm using 1.6.0-beta.

Comment: I used standard VS2015 professional installation, it is version 1.5.3.

Comment: Thanks for the help Torsten, upvoted. I'll need to take a deeper look into different IDEs and if they throw the same errors.